# Importance of soil adjusted vegetation indices for indoor use

Tags: vegetation, ndvi, plant

I've been doing research on vegetation indices to try and prepare for my indoor plant analysis project.

I have a question about soil adjustments, specifically soil line based indices like PVI.

Is the purpose of soil adjustment to offset the indirect effect that the soil has on the pixels of the green material? or to try and negate the soil values when considering the index value of every pixel across an image?

If the latter is true, would there be value in using computer vision techniques (such as foreground extraction) to remove the background material altogether?